# Click (right and left) does not work with wampserver's tray icon

Tags: wamp, wampserver, trayicon

When I want to show the menus for wamp, nothing happens...

I already reinstalled wampserver, I also installed all the VC redistribuables and I checked if there are all installed with [this tool](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe) (provided by wamp).

Comment: Did you install both the 32bit and 64bit MSVC Runtimes?

Comment: Yes, I installed both.

Comment: Did you install those BEFORE installing WAMPServer?

Comment: Yes, I also uninstalled WAMPServer and "repair" all Runtimes, then I reinstalled WAMP.